# How can I create directories containing file name prefixes?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple (not simple for me though) question.

Let's say, I have a.txt, b.txt, c.txt.
After a repetitive processe, I want save results in separate directories like a_result/a_result.txt, b_result/b_result.txt, c_result/c_result.txt.

How can I do it with a shell script?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know about [`basename(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `${param%word}` form of parameter expansion to strip the `.txt` from the input file name and create the corresponding directory and output file name.

```
for input in a.txt b.txt c.txt; do
    stem=${input%.txt}
    mkdir -p "${stem}_result"
    some_command "$input" > "${stem}_result/${stem}_result.txt"
done
```

Comment: +1, and this makes sense if you are doing something like `for input in *.txt`, but if one is actually spelling out the files it's probably simpler to do `for stem in a b c; do ...`

Comment: How about replacing the `some_command` line with `mv "$input" "${stem}_result/${stem}_result.txt"`

Comment: Thank you, guys! chepner's command worked for me. If I want to use two or more files at the same time like `some_command a_1.txt a_2.txt`, and save in one directory, what should I do?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. If `some_command` produces one output file, what should its name be? If `some_command` produces two output files, then it is writing them itself and not to standard output, so the command itself is responsible for writing them to the correct directory, or you need to move the files once they *are* created.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```sh
for let in a b c; do
    mkdir -p "$let"_result
    some_command "$let".txt > "$let"_result/"$let"_result.txt
done
```